# Installing Windows (10 LTSB) after Manjaro?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, grub, veracrypt, manjaro

I have a problem. As an experiment, and for a specific purpose, I am trying to do install Windows 10 LTSB alongside a LUKS encrypted Manjaro system (no LVM), encrypt the Windows system with VeraCrypt and make it so it it dualbootable. I know installing Windows will erase the bootloader, and I know I have to install it on a prepared NTFS partition and that's where my knowledge ends. I need help with configuring GRUB and anything else, with Veracrypt.

Additonal info: the SSD I want to install Windows on is GPT and has the Linux partition on it, as well as all else needed to boot it normally.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It used to be said that for dual booting install Windows first. But with UEFI that's a moot point. Correctly installed you can boot both OSes from the UEFI boot menu independently and regardless of which was installed first. Grub can also work in tandem with the UEFI bootloader giving users a second chance to select Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use **[rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)**!
It's really easy to install it under the most major Linux disros. I, personally use Manjaro.

```
$ pacman -Ss refind
# pacman -S refind-efi
# refind-install --help
```

Read more by given link. It should work out of the box. And there are a lot to customize for your taste.

I cannot say about exact steps to do. The common idea is install rEFInd to basic EFI partition of GPT disk. It will automatically look for other `*.efi`s and will allow to select between windows and linux before grub.

**Caution! EFI/UEFI only, no BIOS supported**
*I believe you have UEFI in 2017* :)
There is nothing to do with old BIOS. Actually there are a lot of s_x with grub